# Proof that any every operator on a finite-dimensional,nonzero,real vector space has an invariant subspace of dimension 1 or 2

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace

in Steven Roman's Advanced linear algebra, the author prove the theorem in the following way: suppose that f is a real linear operator and then factors its minimal polynomial m(x) into a product of linear and quadratic factors over R, if there is a linear factor $x-\lambda $then we can take the subspace spanned by the eigen vector, otherwise, let p(x)=$x^2+ax+b$ be an irreducible quadratic factor of m(x) and write m(x)=p(x)q(x), since $q(f)\neq0$, we may choose a nonzero vector v such that $q(f)v\neq0$, let $W=span(q(f)v,fq(f)v)$, then I have proved that W is invariant under f, **but how to show that W has dimension 2**?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but since $W$ is the span of $2$ vectors, $\dim W \leq 2$. That is enough for the proof.

Comment: @Mason what do you mean by saying "That is enough for the proof."

Comment: $W$ is invariant under $f$ and $\dim W \in \{1, 2\}$, so that proves the theorem. Actually $W$ can't have dimension $1$ because that would mean $f$ has an eigenvector. So $\dim W = 2$.

Comment: $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto 0$ is a linear operator on the finite-dimensional, non-zero real vector space $\Bbb R$ whose only invariant subspace has dimension $0$. (I.e., $f$ also has to be non-zero, not just the vector space.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair If $f = 0$, then any subspace is invariant under $f$ since if $W$ is a subspace, $f(W) = \{0\} \subseteq W$.

Comment: @Mason - I see. I was putting a more stringent meaning on invariant. My mistake.